# JavaScript string replace IE problem

Tags: javascript, string, internet-explorer-8, replace

This simple code  works fine in FF and Chrome... but not in IE8:

```
var pathtop = $('#autoplay').find('embed').attr('src');
pathtop = pathtop.replace('http://www.youtube.com/v/', '');
```

Gives:

> 'undefined' is null or not an object error on line 2

I also tried something like this:

```
pathtop = pathtop.replace('', '');
```

and the same error!

I am using jQuery in this project.

Answer (score 3):

pathtop on IE is most likely null, because the jquery find/attr chain failed. Split it up into parts and find out which layer ($('#autoplay'), `.find()` or `.attr()` is returning a null.

Offhand guess - IE's ignoring embed tags in favor of `<object>`, so there's no embed in the DOM tree. and you're trying to get the src of a non-existence dom object, making pathtop null, which means there's no replace method available for it.

Comment: Sounds like a good guess to me with the limited info we have (no HTML to match to the code).

Comment: I see.. i am trying to get the attr scr from that comes from an ajax text call. Any idea hoe to make it?

<object height="400" width="664">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/T_Mt6Isew_0&amp;autoplay=1">
<param name="WMODE" value="transparent">
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/T_Mt6Isew_0&amp;autoplay=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" wmode="transparent" height="400" width="664">
</object>

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var pathtop = $('#autoplay').find('object').attr('src');
pathtop = pathtop.replace('http://www.youtube.com/v/', '');
```

Comment: hi Maxx, just tried but seems ie is making making pathtop null so same error... any other idea of how i could have a solution, thanks!

Comment: i might have to send the src value ( that comes from ajax call ) separated from this html code... and than split it in some way... i think!